# Bootstrap glyphicon not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to the ASP environment and I am building an application using Visual Studio 2013 with Bootstrap V.3.0.0.

I have this for the `Site.Master`:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
           <li><a runat="server" href="~/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>Home</a></li>
           <li><a runat="server" href="~/ProducersList"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Producers</a></li>
           <li><a runat="server" href="~/BeatsList"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-music"></span>Beats</a></li>
           <li><a runat="server" href="~/License"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>License</a></li>
           <li><a runat="server" href="~/About"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>About</a></li>
           <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>Contact</a></li>
           <li><a runat="server" href="~/ShoppingCart" id="cartCount"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></a></li>
      </ul>
```

Code behind `Site.Master` for `Cart::`

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (ShoppingCartActions usersShoppingCart = new ShoppingCartActions())
    {
          string cartStr = string.Format("Cart ({0})", usersShoppingCart.GetCount());
          cartCount.InnerText = cartStr;
    }
}
```

All the glyphicons show except the last one, `glyphicon-shopping-cart`. What do I change to get it to show?

Comment: Are you certain that the class is defined? Have you checked the computed CSS to see if the styles from the class have been rendered?

Comment: open the page in chrome and see the markup by pressing F12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your icon disappears because you are replacing the whole content of your cartCount hyperlink with the item count: [MSDN tells that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.innertext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Assigning a value to InnerText will destroy any child elements that
>   belong to the element.

So your `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>` doesn't survive the `InnerText` assignation. What you could rather do is to place the cart count inside your wrapping hyperlink:

```
<li>
    <a href="~/ShoppingCart">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
        <span  id="cartCount" runat="server" />
    </a>
</li>
```

and change the code to assign the computed string to the `Text` property of the cartCount span, this should work.

If having a span inside your link is not desirable, you can use a `LiteralControl` to keep the result as raw text